# How do I access parse-dashboard on bitnami parse vm

Tags: parse-server, bitnami

I have installed parse server using bitnami parse vm on virtual box. I am trying to get to the dashboard without success. I keep getting 404 when I navigate to /parse, /, /dashboard.

Comment: You installed the dashboard, but didn't run the ExpressJS server?

Comment: I'd try using Docker anyways. https://github.com/yongjhih/docker-parse-server

Comment: Hi, Bitnami developer here.

Bitnami Parse Stack includes Parse Dashboard since version 2.2.6-1. It should be accessible in `/`.

You can check if all the servers are running by executing `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`


Also, you could check the logs in order to figure out the issue. Apache logs are under `/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/`. For checking `forever` logs, execute the commands `sudo /opt/bitnami/use_parse; forever logs`. I hope it helps.